# Python regular expression remove period from number at end of sentence

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string as such:
   "I like the numbers 3.142 and 2."

And I want to remove the period after 2 but not the one in 3.142, how should I perform this? Basically, how do I check if a number followed by a period doesn't have numbers following the period and how do I remove that period? Thanks.

Comment: Google `Negative lookbehinds` :)

Comment: If trying to remove a period at the end of the line is what your after, then the number should have nothing to do with it. If trying to remove periods that do not have digits after it, then that is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "I. always. like the numbers 3.142, 5., 6.12 and 2. Lalala."

>>> re.sub('((\d+)[\.])(?!([\d]+))','\g<2>',s)
'I. always. like the numbers 3.142, 5, 6.12 and 2 Lalala.'
```

Comment: If you'll use the sentence: `"I like the numbers 3.142 and 2. and lalala."` it will remove the last dot - which it shouldn't.

Comment: found one of the ways to fix it :) It might be also possible to make it distinguish between the dot at the end of the sentence, assuming the next sentence always begins from the capital letter or a number, but I guess there might be more corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

Wrikken wrote a good solution in the comments above, 
it removes the dot only when it comes after a digit and is not followed by a digit:

```
import re
sen = "I like the numbers 3.142 and 2. and lalala."
p = re.compile("(?<=\d)(\.)(?!\d)")
new_sen = p.sub("",sen)
print (new_sen)  #prints: I like the numbers 3.142 and 2 and lalala.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to delete a period at the end of a line:

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence = "I like the numbers 3.142 and 2."
>>> re.sub(r'\.+$', '', sentence)
'I like the numbers 3.142 and 2'
```

If you want to delete any decimals not followed by a digit, use negative lookahead:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\.(?!\d)', '', sentence)
'I like the numbers 3.142 and 2'
```

Comment: This is true if you take the question very literal, but the OP asks for the second, but we aren't sure if that's always the case :). I think it's better to first get more details than guessing the answer. Still nothing wrong with the answer on itself tho :)

Comment: Now it will remove dots from the middle of the line: "I had a cat. His name was Johnny" --> "I had a cat His name was Johnny". The requirement is to remove only dots when they come after a digit and no digit follows: `\d\.\D` --> `\d\.`

Comment: @alfasin OP wanted to "remove period from ... end of sentence." It's not clear that this is unintended behavior.

Comment: @GVH the OP specifically writes: "Basically, how do I check if a number followed by a period doesn't have numbers following the period" -- it has nothing to do with the end of the line

Comment: Yes, the requirement is as alfasin mentioned. I don't wanna remove periods in the middle of the string as well.

Answer (score 0):

In multi-line mode, this should work. Use in global context.
This will process multi-lined strings in one go.
It finds the last period, with optional non-newline whitespace to the end of line
checked with a lookahead assertion.

Find:

```
\.(?=[^\S\r\n]*$)
```

Replace: `""`

Comment: Same comment I wrote to Ashalynd applies to this regex.

Comment: @alfasin - Sorry man, but until he changes the _TITLE_ `regular expression remove period from number at end of sentence`, I'm sticking with this.